# external css file in laravel

Tags: css, laravel

I have added **Bootstrap 4**  in app.blade.php in my **Laravel Project**. Now I'm trying to add an external css file in my project but my css file is not working no even in layout.blade.php and view.blade.php.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<title>{{ config('adminDashboard.name', 'Dashboard ML') }}</title>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

<!-- Fonts -->
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Bootstrap Link start -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Styles -->
   <!--  <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

 -->  external css's file link
 **<link href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />** 

</head>
```

I just placed the styles.css file inside the public\css folder where app.css file is already exist.
Please let me know how can I apply my css affect perfectly. Where should I place my stles.css file?

Comment: `public/css` folder is the place where you put it. How do you know it doesn't work? Have you taken a look at the source of the page to see if it's there? Have you tried calling `/css/styles.css` or using your browser's DevTools Network tab to see if it gets loaded?

Comment: Yes styles.css file exist inside public/css folder. When I try to call some classes from the styles.css file it doen't work properly, and effect of classes not apply on the tags where I call a class of css.